# AUTH_USER vs LOGON_USER vs REMOTE_USER

Tags: php, windows, single-sign-on

I'm wanting to be able to get the information of the logged in user when they come on to our site so they don't need to log in. 
I've been told that it's only possible in I.E when your on windows IE. once they have signed in with their windows credentials.

I've searched the net and all three of these (`$_SERVER['AUTH_USER']`, `$_SERVER['LOGON_USER']`, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']`) had been recommended so I'm not sure which one to check.

Second of all, I'm using windows server with IIS and no matter what I've tried and searched for on the net but nothing works. 
I can see the variables in the `$_SERVER` but all the above are empty strings.

How do I fix this problem?

For reference I'm using windows server 2012 with php v7.1

Also in my php.ini file I see that all of them have the following values.

`$_SERVER['LOGON_USER']: no value`  (like so)

but I've also searched on how to set these in the .ini file without much luck.

```
header('WWW-Authenticate: NTLM', true);


// with this die there is a user and password prompt 
// if i click cancel then it sends the information through to the 
// server vars as expected.     
// when we cancel here it registers as two requests as my logs in the 
// log shows up two times.

// without it the login page loads with symfony but no values ever
// come through and i cant log in the user. 
die();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do so, the systems should be on a intranet network!

You can get system Username easily with the code below:

```
<?php echo getenv("username"); ?>
```

In order to obtain the logged in user firstly ensure you have windows authentication enabled and anonymous disabled. You have to send the NTLM-Authenticate headers first. After that, there should be the right user in the $_SERVER-Vars

```
header('WWW-Authenticate: NTLM');
$_SERVER['AUTH_USER'];
```

This only works on I.E and also you need to configure I.E for Automatic Logon

To configure Internet Explorer for automatic logon

- Open the Internet Options dialog box by choosing Internet Options
  either from Control Panel or from the Tools menu in Internet
  Explorer.
- In the Internet Options dialog box, on the Security tab, select Local
  intranet, and then click Custom Level.
- In the Security Settings dialog box, under Logon, select Automatic
  logon only in Intranet zone, and then click OK.
- In the Internet Options dialog box on the Security Settings tab with
  Local intranet still selected, click Sites.
- In the Local intranet dialog box, click Advanced.
- In the next dialog box (also titled Local intranet), type the URL of
  your Communicator Web Access site (for example,
  https://cwaserver.contoso.com) in the Add this Web site to the zone
  box, and then click Add.
- In the Local intranet dialog, box click OK.
- In the original Local intranet dialog box, click OK.
- In the Internet Options dialog box, click OK.

Comment: Ok I've done everything you have said and now every time i go onto my site from the browser on the server desktop it opens up a login prompt.

Comment: @TheMan68 Have you done the auto login settings ? AND also 

Add the domain to the "Local Intranet Sites" in security in IE. That will log in the current user that is logged into the PC.

Comment: see this link from official website https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd572939(v=office.13).aspx

Comment: Yes I followed all the steps that you put in

Comment: Ill go through the steps once again and double check everything. But if I can't solve it now then ill have to do it tomorrow when I come back to work. Thank you very much

Comment: It is working. But the login prompt still keeps poping up. but if i click cancel it still lets me progress to the page and i get all the user vars like expected

Comment: I've updated my question. Nothing much just a little better than explaining everything here. thank you got your help. with your help I've still spent just short of a day on this. without you could have been a lot longer. thank you

Comment: You're very welcome. Happy to hear that. It sound like the privacy settings of your I.E is not well set. Check with your up address instead of domain name and check the result.

Comment: I've added h t t p://ip, ip, h t t ps://ip and none of them work. And I am right in thinking that i need to set these settings on my internet explorer on my server machine or the IE on my personal windows computer?

Comment: that should be added on the client machine as you allow the website to access your client credentials

Comment: I did also try that but even still I'm always getting this credentials popup. I've gone through what you have sent and many other resources online and its the same on every machine I try.

Answer (score 1):

**AUTH_USER**

The name of the user as it is derived from the authorization header sent by the client, before the user name is mapped to a Windows account. This variable is no different from **REMOTE_USER**.

**LOGON_USER**

The only time LOGON_USER holds a different value than these other variables is if you have an authentication filter installed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524602(v=vs.90).aspx